# Align labels under input boxes using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how to go about getting the effect I want here. I have two input boxes that are on the same line and I want to have labels underneath them and aligned to match the respective input box.

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="decimal_input">Label 1</label>
          <input type="text" value="1" width="10" id="decimal_input" class="form-control" />
          = <label for="input2">Label 2</label> 
          <input type="text" value="I" width="30" id="input2" class="form-control" />
      </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Take a look at the jsfiddle here for more info:

http://jsfiddle.net/justinhj/bTVKZ/2/

Comment: Can you change the HTML? If not, you will have to use some kind of positioning or negative margins to get the label text under the input fields. If you can, I would just put the input fields _into_ the label elements, with the label text after them (still inside the label element) – and then just give the labels and the input the same width.

Comment: Your HTML is improperly nested, both here and in your fiddle. Use the TidyUp button as a syntax checker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bTVKZ/6

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <input type="text" value="1" width="10" id="decimal_input" class="form-control" />
                <br />
                <label for="decimal_input">Label 1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" value="I" width="30" id="input2" class="form-control" />
                <br />
                <label for="input2">Label 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your opinion on using `br` tags to force a line break on elements? I've always thought they should be used to force line breaks for text within `p` tags.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree--I don't normally use them for layout. I did it as a quick fix. There are certainly other options.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**Extra CSS:**

```
label {
   display:block;
}

.form-group {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Modified HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" value="1" width="10" id="decimal_input" class="form-control" />
            <label for="decimal_input">Label 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" value="I" width="30" id="input2" class="form-control" />
            <label for="input2">Label 2</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bTVKZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your new HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="inner-container">
                <label for="decimal_input">Label 1</label>
                <input type="text" value="1" width="10" id="decimal_input" class="form-control" />
            </span>
            =
            <span class="inner-container">
                <label for="input2">Label 2</label>
                <input type="text" value="I" width="30" id="input2" class="form-control" />
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
</diV>
```

Your new CSS (of course I would add a class to the labels):

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.inner-container {
    position: relative;
}

label {
    top: 25px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7CRe/2/)